# Meaning of covariance matrix row sums

Tags: covariance, random-variable, variance-decomposition

Say I have an $n \times n$ covariance matrix for a sample set of $n$ random variables.  Is there any meaning if the sum of the rows of this matrix?  Is it a meaningful measurement of the contribution of each random variable to the variance of sum of the random variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sum of all the elements of the covariance matrix is the variance of the sum of the random variables involved:

$$\operatorname {Var} \left(\sum_i^nX_i\right) = \sum_i^n\operatorname {Var}(X_i) + 2\sum_{i\neq j}\operatorname {Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

The sum of  row $i$ is

$$\operatorname {Var}(X_i) + \sum_{i\neq j}\operatorname {Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

To the degree that you are willing to "split the difference" or "share the blame equally" between the two random variables that form each pair (and so "allocate" one $\operatorname {Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ to $X_i$ and the other to $X_j$), then (responding to comments) by dividing this sum by the sum of all the elements of the covariance matrix  (i.e. by the Variance of the sum of rv's), you could argue that this ratio is indeed a measure of how much each r.v. contributes in relative terms to the variance of the sum.

Comment: The analysis is good (+1), but you should divide the row sum by the sum of all entries to obtain something meaningful: row sums by themselves tell you nothing whatsoever about the "contribution" of the variable to the variance of the sum.

Comment: @whuber Indeed, to get a "percentage" measure (I just thought it obvious, but I updated my answer nevertheless).

Comment: @whuber , AlecosPapadopoulos, Is there logic behind dividing $2Cov(X_j,X_k)$ between $j$ and $k$ into exact halves? I mean, is there any reason to prefer this splitting instead another fractions? I cannot see it clearly when the random variables are different to each other.

Comment: @user1420303 Covariance is a symmetric concept, so we have no basis, logical or other, to "allocate" it in any other way, irrespective of how different the two random variables are.

Comment: +1. It is important to note that this sum can also be negative for some r.v.'s, meaning that even though its variance is obligatory positive, it is so negatively correlated with the other variables that it reduces the variance of the overall sum.